# Multiple projects on one domain

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a domain that is used for multiple landing pages.

example:

```
domain.com/A/
domain.com/B/
```

Each has its own firebase project, server key, sender ID etc.
I am testing using my phone, goto landing page A - sign up for notifications.
Then, I do the same on B.

After signing up on B, I send a message to the registrants for A list, but I stop getting notified on A (on my phone).
Is there a way around that?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean about _stop getting notified on A_? Are you signing on on both applications using the same mobile app?

Comment: @JPVentura I use the same phone to go to both pages to sign up. than, I try sending a notification to both lists, and it seems that after signing up for B, I stop getting notifications from A.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the context of this question, you are trying to integrate two apps to function as one, and in one project you have group *A*, while in the other you have group *b*.

If that is the case, that means that the apps function in the same way, and you are needing multiple databases per projects, which is available through the [Blaze plan](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/?authuser=0).

Comment: not exactly. I do not want to use send-groups. I want the two (A and B) to be strangers (so I tried to set them up individually).

Comment: I am using one FireBase account and I am on the free plan so I am limited to one DB. Is this the problem? Locally I have multiple DBs but now that I think about it, is there actually one DB in FireBase and when I register with my phone to A -> then B, it actually replaces the A registration? because it sees both projects as one?

Comment: With the free plan, you are limted to one DB per project, which means that the database in project A is seperate from the database in project B.

Comment: Also, why do you need two landing pages?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. I want 2 different solutions (A and B are strangers to each other) -> do I just need each to have its own FireBase account? [ I am looking for a solution in which per landing page I will have a notification list. each landing page is for a different client ]

Comment: Sorry for lateness.

In one Firebase account, you can create multiple projects. Each project will be entirely different.
Creating two separate accounts and creating one project on each account will do the same thing, but with much more hassle.

So the best thing to do is to create two separate projects with one account.

Comment: I tried that, I can only create 1 DB on the free plan but I had 2 projects. it didn't seem to help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165252/discussion-between-battlesquid-and-tarkil).